# Clutter on OSX -- "Unable to find suitable GL visual" error

Tags: clutter, clutter-gui

I am looking to try out clutter (http://www.clutter-project.org) on an OSX machine (10.6). I installed the toolkit first by setting up required dependencies via macports and then installing clutter from source (with needed osx flags).

When I try to compile any sample code, it succeeds. However, I always get a "ClutterGLX-CRITICAL **: Unable to find suitable GL visual." error.

I tried googling for answers but couldn't find anything useful.

Help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the same problem on my MacBook using the standard build from MacPorts, but the no_x11 variant worked okay for me. I am also using the universal variant because I'm using the library from a 32-bit app, so this is what my MacPorts command line looked like:

```
sudo port install clutter +universal +no_x11
```

You can probably omit the '+universal' if you only want the library built for your default architecture.